# Fatal error: Out of memory Error on WampServer

Tags: php, wamp

I have set memory_limit to -1 in php.ini file in Wampserver.
My RAM is 6 Go.
But I still getting this error:
Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1673789440) (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\livre_scraping1\api\simple_html_dom.php on line 1353

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is PHP running as an Apache module on WampServer?  If so, check your `.htaccess` file for the server and look for the line `php_value memory_limit xxxx`.  It may be overriding the `php.ini` value

Comment: Where can I find the .htaccess file?

Comment: It should be in the `\wamp\www\\ ` directory.  If it isn't there, there may not be one.  You could create one and add that line and see if it helps.  If you create a new `.htaccess` file, you should also uncomment the line `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in your `httpd.conf` file which should be in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 `php.ini` files, I would guess yo are editing the wrong one.

Use the wampmanager menus to make sure you edit the correct one, like so :-

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

This is the `php.ini` file actually used by PHP when running under Apache

The other one `\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini` is used bu PHP CLI i.e. when running PHP from the command line.